# How do I combine several images into a single one?

Tags: image-processing

Is there a program that let's me choose separate image files and output it as one whole image with the images lined up horizontally as a transparent gif?

Comment: Voting to migrate to Super User. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Jahkr The question as it's currently written is off topic unless you are looking for code to do this... but you'd have to rewrite the question and specify a language.

Answer (score 1):

Imagemajik does all kinds of things like this at the command line, and is free:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I would try looking for "panoramic stitcher" programs, since that's essentially what you are trying to do.

- http://hugin.sourceforge.net/
- http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~brown/autostitch/autostitch.html